How do FOX and CBS manage halftime shows for multiple NFL games that often don't reach halftime simultaneously?
I'm curious about the logistics behind how networks like FOX and CBS broadcast halftime shows for multiple NFL games airing at the same time. Given that these games often have different paces and may not reach halftime at the exact same moment, how do the networks coordinate their coverage?

Out of interest, for someone not in the US, what is it about the broadcast that doesnt make it obvious?

@TheFootsie, the networks air different games in different regions each with their own local crew.   But all the games cut to a live-broadcast national "show" with information about other games going on during their halftime break.  As the halftimes of each game are not synchronized and the same national crew is shown for all the different regions, you might wonder if the show is truly live or how it works that you never appear to be joining them "in-progress".

The halftime shows aren't very long.   NFL halftime is only a bit more than 12 minutes.   With commercials and the local crew doing the intro to the second half, there's only maybe 5 minutes of network show.   And that can be cut down a bit if necessary.
So if there's a couple of games that are ending at nearly the same time, the director can prep it so the show for those 2 markets are the same one.   Otherwise they move commercials around so that the shows can be back-to-back.
One network won't normally have more than 5 games in a timeslot, so with a lot of coordination, it can all get fit together.

It used to be standard (1960s to not sure when) for the halftime crew to welcome viewers from another game, give a quick update of that game's score, then proceed on with the highlights or other stuff. This occurred for halftime and post-game shows.
